# Regular conditional probability for the 0-1 sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal F := \{A \in \mathcal A \mid P(A) \in \{0,1 \}\}$. Show that $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and find a regular conditional probability $P(\cdot\mid\mathcal F)(\cdot)$.

The proof of $\mathcal F$ being a $\sigma$-algebra is not the problem. But for the
regular conditional probability, I know, that 
\begin{align}
E(X\mid\mathcal F)=E(X)
\end{align}  for $X:(\Omega, \mathcal A, P) \rightarrow (E, \mathcal E)$.

I think because of 
\begin{align}
P(A\mid\mathcal F)(\omega):=E(\mathbb{1}_{A}\mid\mathcal F)(\omega)
\end{align}
for $A \in \mathcal A$,
I can deduce 
\begin{align}
P(X \in B\mid \mathcal F)=P(X \in B) 
\end{align}
for $B \in \mathcal E$.

If $P(X \in B)$ would be a markov kernel, I would have found my regular conditional probability here. So now I have to somehow get $P(X\in B)$ to be a markov kernel. But how to do so?

Are my thoughts going in the right direction? Maybe someone can help me. I don't think it is that difficult, but I don't see it right now...

Comment: One take-home message from the solution below is that conditional probabilities do not necessarily refer to random variables, but only to events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [RCP](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7UuT7UZViN0C&pg=PA341&dq=10.2.%20Regular%20Conditional%20Probabilities&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwra_jnNXUAhVY6GMKHQ_CBcwQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=10.2.%20Regular%20Conditional%20Probabilities&f=false) must satisfy:

1. For each $A\in \mathcal{A},$ $\mathsf{P}(A\mid\mathcal{F})(\cdot)=\mathsf{E}[1_A\mid\mathcal{F}](\cdot)$, $\mathsf{P}\mid_{\mathcal{F}}-$a.s., where $\mathsf{P}(A\mid\mathcal{F})(\cdot)$ is measurable for $\mathcal{F}$;
2. For every $\omega\in\Omega$, $\mathsf{P}(\cdot\mid\mathcal{F})(\omega)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$.

Since, for $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and any $F\in\mathcal{F}$, $\int 1_{F\cap A}d\mathsf{P}=\int\mathsf{P}(A)1_Fd\mathsf{P}$, $\mathsf{P}(A)$ is a version of $\mathsf{E}[1_A\mid \mathcal{F}]$. Moreover, since $\mathsf{P}(A)$ is a constant, it is measurable for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathsf{P}$ is trivially a probability measure on $\mathcal{A}$ for each $\omega\in \Omega$.